# Trying to push vertices inside of a function with Three js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to create a template function to push multiple equilateral triangles to a scene based on parameters passed through the function. This is the current method I am using:

```
        function createEquiTri(x, y, sideLength){
            var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

            geometry.verticies.push( new THREE.Vector3(x,(Math.sqrt(3)/2*sideLength)-(sideLength/2),0));
            geometry.verticies.push( new THREE.Vector3(x-(sideLength/2),y-(sideLength/2),0));
            geometry.verticies.push( new THREE.Vector3(x+(sideLength/2),y-(sideLength/2),0));

            geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 0, 1, 2 ));

            var redMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff0000});
            var triangle = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, redMat);
            scene.add(triangle) 
        }

        createEquiTri(0,0,20);
```

However in the console I am receiving an error that I can only attribute to scope saying that says: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined". But I dont know why it would be undefined due to the geometry variable being in the same function.

Comment: which line is it referring to the `faces.push` or the `verticies.push`, depending on which one it is referring to either `verticies` or `faces` does not exist. Look at the structure of the Geometry object to make sure you are accessing the correct property name.

Comment: @PatrickEvans its refering to vertices... and I spelled it wrong. Its always a stupid little mistake. Grahh.